# How to Build a package that doesn't require root

Tags: package-management, debian

I have been following a couple tutorials on how to build a debian package, and have read that I need to make the contents of my package root otherwise it will retain my local users when installed on another computer.

I want to make my system service non root, and to own the directory /etc/mybin/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible since users in a Linux system use an ID to *differentiate* one another, root would have the same in any system. AFAIK all users can use the path `/usr/bin` but only the administrator can write to this folder hence a regular user cannot install a package.

You can add an additional folder to PATH in Bash but you would be required to do this step for each user but how it is actually done is to use a **Tar archive** and run by clicking on the **binary itself**. After uncompressing the archive ofc.

Happy Llamas!